# Linking Storyboard View with Costum View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am fairly new to IOS programming, and i am having small issues linking the view inside the storyboard with the ViewController i creat.

I can do it programmaticly, by editting the storyboard source, but i cannot seem to do it via the interface.

```
<viewController title="Navigation" id="2" customClass="ViewControllerNav" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

works, but if i go in to the interface and set the Costum class to ViewControllerNav, nothing happens, and i get a error on compile?

(It dosnt even show up when i start typing "ViewContr...." etc, its like the class is not registerd there)

Comment: on a side not are you sure your not trying to type it in while the view controller is selected and not a view or something else?

Comment: That could be the issue, i will look in to it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and deleting the XCode cache has fixed this for me (assuming that IB can't see your class when you type it's name). Firstly quit XCode, then delete the cached files by deleting all of the contents of this folder /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
Doing this and then opening xcode again should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Close out xcode and re open i bet it will magically be there. Seriously though, if you can type in custom class in storyboard source then theres nothing wrong with your code, you should even be able to type it into where you type in custom classes, just sometimes after freshly creating it, it wont show.